# How to give Create, Read and Modify permissions to all users for a file created by my application in C:\ProgramData?

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, user-accounts

My application basically creates an XML file in `C:\ProgramData\MyAppFolder` and dumps config settings in it.

I need to allow even standard users to have permission to add or delete settings to these config files. Right now I see that standard users only have read/execute permission but not "Full Control".

I've seen other questions being answered with ways to modify permissions to that particular folder but I don't want to change the default permission level, since it might be reset by a system admin.

If `C:\ProgramData` can't give that access to all users, is there any folder that best suits the needs of application?

EDIT:

My initial question might be misleading. I don't want to give rights to users, but rather allow the application to modify the XML file when it is run by all users.

DECISION:

I think changing the permissions while creating the folder in ProgramData is the only option.

And if that's not possible, CommonDocuments is the way to go.

Thanks Eve.

Comment: `I don't want to change the default permission level, since it might be reset by a system admin.` -- the admin controls permissions on the computer, not you. You can't decide a file will be full control for all users if the admin doesn't want it to be.

Comment: I agree with that. For the exact reason, I want to find out if any other folder will do the job.

Comment: The admin can lock down any files on any folders.

Comment: Admin sure can.
But the reason I mentioned that is I don't want to change the default permissions for a folder, which might unknowingly be reset by the admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a folder in the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum.

Example:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Comment: Won't this be user specific?
I want a single file which can be read/written into by the application when being run by all users.

Comment: You can use: `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments`

Comment: C:\ProgramData = Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData

Comment: @BryanJ He'd return to his initial problem by using that folder.

Comment: @Eve, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your answer. You are suggesting on writing to a different loaction, rather than how to get access to ProgramData. Got it.

Comment: +1. Writing user setting to per-user folder is recommended and much more easier to understand approach. Three-way merges (original + 2 conflicting updates) for files is very interesting problem I'd prefer someone else to deal with :).

Answer (score 1):

Users should not be allowed to write arbitrary data to this directory.  This is equivalent to regular users being able to modify the `C:\Users\AllUsers` directory.  If users need to be modifying this directory you have serious design flaws and should reconsider this approach.  What should happen is the users are given GUI interface to interact with that manipulates these values behind the scenes without giving them direct access, similar to how getters/setters work in most programming languages.  Needless to say it is a very large security hole when regular users can corrupt a system for other users.

**UPDATE**

> I don't want to give users direct access to the file. My question
>   might have been misleading. I want to allow the program to have full
>   control on the file even when it being run by all users. I'm actually
>   doing this: "users are given GUI interface to interact with that
>   manipulates these values behind the scenes without giving them direct
>   access"

This [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/09/29/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-4-_1320_-User-Account-Control.aspx)  which has far too much information to post here, will provide details on remaining secure as to not leak permissions.  The first thing you want to do is make sure that your application user is in its own group and cannot login/have any special permissions.  What you can than do is have this group added to the directory with write permissions, which would allow this application to perform these tasks.  If that is not possible you will need to work within UAC to not break the security of the system as is detailed in the article above.

**Second Update**

> Thanks for the link. Any suggestions on some other folder which can do
>   the job, rather than messing with the permissions?

Sure you can write it into the directory where the application is written to, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Some Awesome Program`, this keeps everything in one place, and you only have to worry about your user/group and anything that the person who installed it has allowed for.  It also prevents other people from messing with it unless of course they are administrators.

Comment: I don't want to give users direct access to the file. My question might have been misleading.
I want to allow the program to have full control on the file even when it being run by all users.
I'm actually doing this: "users are given GUI interface to interact with that manipulates these values behind the scenes without giving them direct access"

Comment: Thanks for the link. Any suggestions on some other folder which can do the job, rather than messing with the permissions?

Comment: You can't have your application writing to Program Files, at least not on Vista and later.

Comment: @BryanJ I was pretty sure my postgres install at home wrote to program files, unless I am missing something in what you are saying

Comment: @Woot4Moo, You can't write to ProgramFiles but I'm not sure of the exact rules. It may redirect your writes to a safe location, and it may depend on whether or not you are an admin. But basically writing to program files is a no-no except during installation.

Comment: @BryanJ ah maybe that is the disconnect on my side, I havent checked the permissions of the postgres user, I should see if it drops it into `programdata`

Comment: @Woot4Moo, this thread has some info: http://superuser.com/questions/384107/why-cant-i-edit-a-program-files-file-on-windows-7

Comment: @Woot4Moo, also think I read when Win7 first came out that such virtualization and redirection of the file system may only be temporary, used as a measure to force people to change to the recommended way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an installer for your application, your installer can create a subfolder in the common appdata directory (aka C:\ProgramData) which your application will have read/write access to. Depending on your choice of installation technology you can set the permissions on that folder as well, although that may be overkill. I know with [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) basically all you have to do is a per-machine installation and make sure that sub folder gets created.